# Design Pattern to Parse Setting Files

Tags: c#, parsing, design-patterns

I have been trying to find an elegant solution to parse settings files.

Below is an example:

```
L09D21=Type:OPT Z:0000 F:---A-Z--- S:+0 AVF:OFF Desc:"AHU-QCH 07.05EX PROBE" Out:,
G195=Out:LED0799,LED0814,Flags:L-N Desc:"EAF-QCH-B1-01" Invert:00 STO:35 SP:0 FStart: FStop: 
SysEv01=Type:FANLATCH Out:LED1165
```

Each line could have a different mapping and multiple of the same line types can be in the file. (These setting come from hardware devices that we need to configure)

Our current code consists out of Multiple/nested switch statements that decode each part of the file/line.

Is there a design pattern that I could look at that solves a similar problem?

My feeling is that there is some kind of polymorphic solution that I am not seeing at the moment

Comment: Try to ask this question on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ . If you are asking for some refactoring quidelines it would be good to show some code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at the simplest line:

```
SysEv01=Type:FANLATCH Out:LED1165
```

From that we can read that we have a setting name and then a bunch of properties. The setting name is delimited using `=` and the properties are separated by a white space. Finally we can also  see that property name/value are separated by colon.

```
public class Setting
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public IDictionary<string, string> Properties{ get; }
}
```

Let's look at the most complex line to verify this:

```
G195=Out:LED0799,LED0814,Flags:L-N Desc:"EAF-QCH-B1-01" Invert:00 STO:35 SP:0 FStart: FStop:
```

Seems to apply. What's interesting is that the value can be omitted, so we have to take that into account when parsing. another thing is that property values can be wrapped with quotes (`"EAF-QCH-B1-01"`).

So let's write a simple parser and test it. The easiest way to being is to just parse a single line to get the different parts from it. Let's start by just getting the setting name and a string for all contents:

```
public class Setting
{
    public Setting(string name)
    {
        if (name == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("name");
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }
}

public class SettingsParser
{
    public Setting ExtractLine(string line)
    {
        var pos = line.IndexOfAny(new[] {'='});
        var setting = new Setting(line.Substring(0, pos));
        return setting;
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class ParserTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Should_be_able_to_extract_name_from_a_line()
    {
        var line = "G195=Out:LED0799,LED0814,Flags:L-N Desc:\"EAF-QCH-B1-01\" Invert:00 STO:35 SP:0 FStart: FStop: ";

        var sut = new SettingsParser();
        var actual = sut.ExtractLine(line);

        Assert.AreEqual("G195", actual.Name);
    }
}
```

We have a minor problem with that code, and that's if the line is malformed. Let's make sure that we get a equals sign and that's it's found before a colon.

```
public Setting ExtractLine(string line)
{
    var pos = line.IndexOfAny(new[] {'=', ':'});
    if (pos == -1 || line[pos] == ':')
        throw new FormatException("Expected an equals sign and that it's positioned before the first colon");

    var setting = new Setting(line.Substring(0, pos));

    return setting;
}
```

Now let's continue to extract the parameters. To take the simplest possible approach we just split the string on space and then go through each entry and split it on colon.

the code is now:

```
public class Setting
{
    public Setting(string name)
    {
        if (name == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("name");
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public IDictionary<string,string> Parameters { get; set; }
}

public class SettingsParser
{
    public Setting ExtractLine(string line)
    {
        var pos = line.IndexOfAny(new[] {'=', ':'});
        if (pos == -1 || line[pos] == ':')
            throw new FormatException("Expected an equals sign and that it's positioned before the first colon");

        var setting = new Setting(line.Substring(0, pos));
        setting.Parameters= ExtractParameters(line.Substring(pos + 1));

        return setting;
    }

    private IDictionary<string, string> ExtractParameters(string paramString)
    {
        var keyValues = paramString.Split(' ');
        var items = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (var keyValue in keyValues)
        {
            var pos = keyValue.IndexOf(':');
            if (pos == -1)
                throw new FormatException("Expected a colon for property " + keyValue);

            items.Add(keyValue.Substring(0, pos), keyValue.Substring(pos + 1));
        }

        return items;
    }
}
```

And the test for this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Should_be_able_to_extract_a_single_parameter()
{
    var line = "G195=Out:LED0799";

    var sut = new SettingsParser();
    var actual = sut.ExtractLine(line);

    Assert.AreEqual("LED0799", actual.Parameters["Out"]);
}

[TestMethod]
public void should_be_able_to_parse_multiple_properties()
{
    var line = "G195=Out:LED0799 Invert:00";

    var sut = new SettingsParser();
    var actual = sut.ExtractLine(line);

    Assert.AreEqual("00", actual.Parameters["Invert"]);
}
```

Fast forward and you got this solution. The code uses a simple loop and `string.IndexOf` as it have to take into account the following scenarios:

- Property without a value
- Quoted property values
- Single property
- Multiple properties

Code:

```
public class Setting
{
    public Setting(string name)
    {
        if (name == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("name");
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public IDictionary<string,string> Parameters { get; set; }
}

public class SettingsParser
{
    public Setting ExtractLine(string line)
    {
        var pos = line.IndexOfAny(new[] {'=', ':'});
        if (pos == -1 || line[pos] == ':')
            throw new FormatException("Expected an equals sign and that it's positioned before the first colon");

        var setting = new Setting(line.Substring(0, pos));
        setting.Parameters= ExtractParameters(line.Substring(pos + 1));

        return setting;
    }

    private IDictionary<string, string> ExtractParameters(string paramString)
    {
        var oldPos = 0;
        var items = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        while (true)
        {
            var pos = paramString.IndexOf(':', oldPos);
            if (pos == -1)
                break;  // no more properties
            var name = paramString.Substring(oldPos, pos - oldPos);


            oldPos = pos +1; //set that value starts after name and colon
            if (oldPos >= paramString.Length)
            {
                items.Add(name, paramString.Substring(oldPos));
                break;//last item and without value
            }
            if (paramString[oldPos] == '"')
            {
                // jump to before quote
                oldPos += 1;
                pos = paramString.IndexOf('"', oldPos);
                items.Add(name, paramString.Substring(oldPos, pos - oldPos));
            }
            else
            {
                pos = paramString.IndexOf(' ', oldPos);
                if (pos == -1)
                {
                    items.Add(name, paramString.Substring(oldPos));
                    break;//no more items
                }

                items.Add(name, paramString.Substring(oldPos, pos - oldPos));
            }


            oldPos = pos + 1;
        }

        return items;

    }

    public KeyValuePair<string, string> ExtractValue(string value, int pos1, int pos2)
    {
        var keyValue = value.Substring(pos1, pos2 - pos1 + 1);
        var colonPos = keyValue.IndexOf(':');
        if (colonPos == -1)
            throw new FormatException("Expected a colon for property " + keyValue);

        return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(keyValue.Substring(0, colonPos),
            keyValue.Substring(colonPos + 1));
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class ParserTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Should_be_able_to_extract_name_from_a_line()
    {
        var line = "G195=Out:LED0799,LED0814,Flags:L-N Desc:\"EAF-QCH-B1-01\" Invert:00 STO:35 SP:0 FStart: FStop: ";

        var sut = new SettingsParser();
        var actual = sut.ExtractLine(line);

        Assert.AreEqual("G195", actual.Name);
    }

    [TestMethod, ExpectedException(typeof(FormatException))]
    public void Setting_name_is_required()
    {
        var line = "G195 malformed";

        var sut = new SettingsParser();
        sut.ExtractLine(line);
    }


    [TestMethod, ExpectedException(typeof(FormatException))]
    public void equals_must_be_before_first_colon()
    {
        var line = "G195:malformed name=value";

        var sut = new SettingsParser();
        sut.ExtractLine(line);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Should_be_able_to_extract_a_single_parameter()
    {
        var line = "G195=Out:LED0799";

        var sut = new SettingsParser();
        var actual = sut.ExtractLine(line);

        Assert.AreEqual("LED0799", actual.Parameters["Out"]);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void should_be_able_to_parse_multiple_properties()
    {
        var line = "G195=Out:LED0799 Invert:00";

        var sut = new SettingsParser();
        var actual = sut.ExtractLine(line);

        Assert.AreEqual("00", actual.Parameters["Invert"]);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void should_be_able_to_include_spaces_in_value_names_if_they_are_wrapped_by_quotes()
    {
        var line = "G195=Out:\"LED0799 Invert:00\"";

        var sut = new SettingsParser();
        var actual = sut.ExtractLine(line);

        Assert.AreEqual("LED0799 Invert:00", actual.Parameters["Out"]);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void second_parameter_value_should_also_be_able_To_be_quoted()
    {
        var line = "G195=In:Stream Out:\"LED0799 Invert:00\"";

        var sut = new SettingsParser();
        var actual = sut.ExtractLine(line);

        Assert.AreEqual("LED0799 Invert:00", actual.Parameters["Out"]);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void allow_empty_values()
    {
        var line = "G195=In:";

        var sut = new SettingsParser();
        var actual = sut.ExtractLine(line);

        Assert.AreEqual("", actual.Parameters["In"]);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void allow_empty_values_even_if_its_not_the_last()
    {
        var line = "G195=In: Out:Heavy";

        var sut = new SettingsParser();
        var actual = sut.ExtractLine(line);

        Assert.AreEqual("", actual.Parameters["In"]);
    }
}
```

**Update in response to comments**

imho the business entities should be built by a builder class that in turn uses the parser as they are two distinct responsibilities. I would use a `Dictionary<string, Func<object>>` to provide factories for each parameter type.

Then you can do something like this:

```
public class CommandBuilder
{
    ParameterParser _parser = new ParameterParser();
    Dictionary<string, Func<Setting, Command>> _builders = new Dictionary<string, Func<Setting, Command>>();

    public IEnumerable<Command> Build(string config)
    {
        var settings = _parser.Parse(config);
        foreach (var setting in settings)
        {
            yield return _builders[setting.Name].Build(setting);
        }
    }

    public void Register(string name, Func<Setting, Command> builder)
    {
        _builders[name] = builder;
    }

}
```

Which allows you to register new commands without using a switch statement:

```
var b = new CommandBuilder();
b.Register("SysEv01", setting => {
    var sysEvent = new SysEventCommand();
    sysEvent.Type = setting.Properties["Type"];
    sysEvent.OutPort = setting.Properties["Out"];
    return sysEvent;

});
```

Comment: Thanks for a really nice write-up and explanations. The above is very similar to what we have in place but the interesting part comes from dissecting the KeyValuePair. We currently use a switch that looks at the key and then processes the Value. This can get very big and nested.

Comment: Our continuous integration system then looks at the switch statements and says : "NO,NO,NO!!! You have high risk cyclic complexity and I have already emailed your manager about it..." :)

Comment: My thoughts was to use an IParamaterParser interface and then created parameter parsers based on it that we can iterate though. Passing the parameter KVP to each ParamaterParser and then populating a settings object.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I am slowly consuming the concept in your update. Still not totally sure about the what "public IEnumerable<Command> Build(string config)" does, but I will figure it out shortly.

Answer (score 1):

Judging on the complexity of the values types, I assume that there must be a library from the manufacturer of the hardware that reads this format. Writing your own parser would be unreliable if it isn't based on a full specification.

But if you want to continue, I advice you to write an abstract parser class that contains two parts, first methods to shift over each character from left-to-right, like any .NET reader but without a stream. Second a buffer to hold symbols temporarily. Once you have done that, you can implement it in the parser class and use its methods to evaluate the string. Imagine it like this, each character or word will determine the next action in the parsing process, which is represented by a method. The method can return a result class, or throw an exception if the occuring symbols are not expected. I advice not to use result classes because of the overhead of instantiating and validating them per element to parse. For recursive formats, make sure to implement a maximum depth to prevent a stack overflow.

Never use one method to do all the work, regardless of the format. It could prevent the compiler from doing optimizations like inlining which is crucial for high-performance programs like a parser. Methods which involve nested switch statements or local state variables are nearly always indicating a bad parser design. Also do not use regex **and** a parser, either one of them should have responsibility for the process. Preferably do not use regex for parsing at all.

Comment: Leopold, we are the manufacturer :) Thanks for the advice on the overhead and regex.

Comment: @BertusKruger Alright. Take note that your format looks very similar to the ini format used by a game called Borderlands 2. You can see an example here: http://pastebin.com/HNHZh8kX  
The nestable format that you see at some keys like StatColorMappings is equivalent to JSON, a format that you might already know.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a line based config with ':' as Split separator for each parameter.
So a parser/regex would be:
1. Start of line till '=' -> Section Name
2. ':' backwards to sperator char (',', ' ') is the parameter name.
3. Value goes till next match for 2.

Not at a place to write the code, but that should do it.
You can place the stuff into a dictionary for more comfortable access.