# Parsing data object structure from text string

Tags: python, regex, parsing, text-parsing, pyparsing

I have been trying some things out with the pyparsing module in order to get some understanding of general parsing.
I was given an interview question (which has been submitted, so I don't think there are any ethical problems now) to process a data structure similar to one like the one below from a text file.

```
Collection Top_Level_Collection "Junk1"
{
  Column Date_time_column 1 {"01-21-2011"}
  Collection Pig_Entry "Sammy"
  {
    Column Animal_locations 35 {"Australia", "England", "U.S."}
    Data 4
    {
      4 0 72033 Teeth 2 {1 "2", 1 "3"};
      1 0 36331 Teeth 2 {2 "2", 3 "4"};
      2 3 52535 Teeth 2 {6 "4", 9 "3"};
      4 0 62838 Teeth 2 {3 "7", 7 "6"};
    }
  }
}
```

I can get a really hacky solution with regex and counting columns to extract pieces of the data and put it together, but I would like to expand my knowledge in parsing to do things more eloquently.
It can be seen that the basic structure is "Main abstract data type" first, then followed by an optional "concrete data type", then either a "name" or "number of entries", while being infinitely nestable.

Here is what I got so far on trying to parse into a dictionary:

```
import numpy as np
import pyparsing as pp

test_str = '''
Collection Top_Level_Collection "Junk"
{
  Column Date_time_column 1 {"01-21-2011"}
  Collection Pig_Entry "Sammy"
  {
    Column Animal_locations 35 {"Australia", "England", "U.S."}
    Data 4
    {
      4 0 72033 Teeth 2 {1 "2", 1 "3"};
      1 0 36331 Teeth 2 {2 "2", 3 "4"};
      2 3 52535 Teeth 2 {6 "4", 9 "3"};
      4 0 62838 Teeth 2 {3 "7", 7 "6"};
    }
  }
}
'''
if __name__ == '__main__':
    expr = pp.Forward()

    object_type = pp.Word( pp.alphanums + '_')
    object_ident = pp.Word( pp.alphanums + '_')
    object_name_or_data_num = pp.Word( pp.alphanums + '_".')

    ident_group = pp.Group(object_type + pp.Optional(object_ident) + object_name_or_data_num)
    nestedItems = pp.nestedExpr("{", "}")

    expr << pp.Dict(ident_group + nestedItems)

    all_data_dict = (expr).parseString(test_str).asDict()

    print all_data_dict
    print all_data_dict.keys()
```

which returns:

```
{'Column': (['Date_time_column', '1', (['"01-21-2011"'], {}), 'Collection', 'Pig_Entry', '"Sammy"', (['Column', 'Animal_locations', '35', (['"Australia"', ',', '"England"', ',', '"U.S."'], {}), 'Data', '4', (['4', '0', '72033', 'Teeth', '2', (['1', '"2"', ',', '1', '"3"'], {}), ';', '1', '0', '36331', 'Teeth', '2', (['2', '"2"', ',', '3', '"4"'], {}), ';', '2', '3', '52535', 'Teeth', '2', (['6', '"4"', ',', '9', '"3"'], {}), ';', '4', '0', '62838', 'Teeth', '2', (['3', '"7"', ',', '7', '"6"'], {}), ';'], {})], {})], {}), 'Collection': (['Top_Level_Collection', '"Junk"'], {})}
['Column', 'Collection']
```

However, my hope is that it would return something that can be easily sent to classes in python to create the objects.
My best guess to do this would be to put them in a nested dictionary, with the key being a tuple of the 2 or 3 object types and the value being a dictionary with each key value under it. I.e. Something similar to this:

```
{ (Collection, Top_Level_Collection, "Junk1"):
    { (Column, Date_time_column): ["01-21-2011"], 
      (Collection, Pig_Entry, "Sammy"): 
        { (Column, Animal_locations): ["Australia", "England", "U.S."],
            (Data): [[ 4 0 72033 {(Teeth):[1 "2", 1 "3"]} ]
                    [ 1 0 36331 {(Teeth):[2 "2", 3 "4"]} ]
                    [ 2 3 52535 {(Teeth):[6 "4", 9 "3"]} ]
                    [ 4 0 62838 {(Teeth):[3 "7", 7 "6"]} ]]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? If you have working code you think could be improved, consider http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Its not exactly working, the output I am getting doesnt nest things properly

Comment: @jonrsharpe - He doesn't know the basics to write a parser in the first place, code review will send him right back.

Comment: @chase - See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23998218/3671511)

Answer (score 3):

You will have to create Classes for your data and then use "setParseAction" for the parsers so that you can create whatever data structures you want. For sample, check the simple example below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from pyparsing import *

test_str="Alpha 1\nBeta 2\nCharlie 3"

aStmt = Word(alphas)("name") + Word(nums)("age")

class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

def myParse(t):
    return Person(t.name, t.age)

aStmt.setParseAction(myParse)

for aline in test_str.split('\n'):
    print aline
    print aStmt.parseString(aline)
```